# SQLCMD - using variables '-v' to set dynamic server/database parameters for the sql query to reference

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I have a bat file executing sqlcmd scripts saved off in files, but needs to pass in various server and database locations as variables into the sql query.

A simple version of the query for testing:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM '$(server)'.'$(database)'.schema.table
```

Shouldn't the variables all be replaced with the values? I already did a quick SELECT '$(server)' to verify they are being passed in. But I cannot get the variable to work in the FROM, results in syntax error. Does it keep the single quotes and so it cannot properly set the server/database?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, 
yes, by removing the single quotes it worked perfectly. Turns out my testing of trying to simply select the value to prove it was being passed in, was also not the method to use for setting the server/databases.

```
SELECT '$(server)' --testing that it passed in
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM $(server).$(database).schema.table --working version
```